# How to create custom Divi module?

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins

How can I add a custom module for Divi Wordpress theme?
http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/

Original modules are created in *main-modules.php*

Example:

```
class ET_Builder_Module_Gallery extends ET_Builder_Module { .... }
```

But the `ET_Builder_Module` class is not accessible in my plugin, or in theme *functions.php*

Answer (score 14):

Most other solutions here are way too complex. The simplest way is to load your custom module in the divi specific action hook `et_builder_ready`, like this:

```
add_action( 'et_builder_ready', 'evr_initialize_divi_modules' );

function evr_initialize_divi_modules() {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'ET_Builder_Module' ) ) { return; }

    class EVR_Builder_Module_Testimonial extends ET_Builder_Module {
        function init() {
            $this->name       = esc_html__( 'Testimonial', 'evr' );
            $this->slug       = 'evr_pb_testimonial';
            $this->fb_support = true;

            // ...

        }
    }
}
```

You can find the full demo-code on github. Along with some instructions how to get it work in the all new Divi 3 frontend builder:

https://github.com/stracker-phil/divi3-vb-custom-modules/

Answer (score 7):

Place below in your functions.php file. The include file (I called it custom-modules.php) will be a class that extends ET_Builder_Module (which is very similar to WP_Widget). Just open the file from Divi>>includes>>builder>>main-modules.php. Use any of the preexisting modules as an example or basis for your new one. Copy and paste into your custom-modules.php. New class names, make edits as needed, etc.

```
function doCustomModules(){
 if(class_exists("ET_Builder_Module")){
    include("custom-modules.php");
 }
}

function prepareCustomModule(){
 global $pagenow;

 $is_admin = is_admin();
 $action_hook = $is_admin ? 'wp_loaded' : 'wp';
 $required_admin_pages = array( 'edit.php', 'post.php', 'post-new.php', 'admin.php', 'customize.php', 'edit-tags.php', 'admin-ajax.php', 'export.php' ); // list of admin pages where we need to load builder files
 $specific_filter_pages = array( 'edit.php', 'admin.php', 'edit-tags.php' ); // list of admin pages where we need more specific filtering
 $is_edit_library_page = 'edit.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && 'et_pb_layout' === $_GET['post_type'];
    $is_role_editor_page = 'admin.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['page'] ) && 'et_divi_role_editor' === $_GET['page'];
    $is_import_page = 'admin.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['import'] ) && 'wordpress' === $_GET['import']; // Page Builder files should be loaded on import page as well to register the et_pb_layout post type properly
    $is_edit_layout_category_page = 'edit-tags.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['taxonomy'] ) && 'layout_category' === $_GET['taxonomy'];

 if ( ! $is_admin || ( $is_admin && in_array( $pagenow, $required_admin_pages ) && ( ! in_array( $pagenow, $specific_filter_pages ) || $is_edit_library_page || $is_role_editor_page || $is_edit_layout_category_page || $is_import_page ) ) ) {
    add_action($action_hook, 'doCustomModules', 9789);
 }
}
$theme_data = wp_get_theme();
$parent_data = $theme_data->parent();
if(version_compare((string)$parent_data->Version, "2.5.9", ">")) {
    add_action('et_builder_ready', 'doCustomModules');
} else {
    doCustomModule();
}
```

Comment: Could this be done in a separate plugin instead of a theme? I tried time ago with no luck.

Comment: Yeah, of course. A child theme or a plugin will work identically. Just make sure you have a file that creates the actual custom modules. The code above is just to include that file. I noted (above the code) where to find the pre-existing module code for Divi. Just copy and paste the modules you want to customize or use as a template for your own.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me... I think Doesn't seem to work for me is not called...
Where is the prepareCustomModule() function suppose to be called?

Comment: Could you explain the "New class names" part of the last sentence?

Answer (score 4):

**Important note:** The slug for your custom module *must* contain the string `et_pb_`, or it will be filtered out by the function `et_pb_allowed_modules_list()`.

I was able to add a new Divi module using the following code (requires PHP 5.3+ for the anonymous function):

```php
add_action(is_admin() ? 'wp_loaded' : 'wp', function() {
  require __DIR__ . '/custom-divi-module.php';
}, 20);
```

Inside the included file, copy and paste a `class` from the `wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/main-modules.php` file, then modify to suit your needs. See the example below (copy an actual class from the file mentioned to get the content of each method listed below… I like the `ET_Builder_Module_Code` class for simplicity's sake):

```
class YOUR_MODULE_NAME extends ET_Builder_Module {
  function init() {
    // Name, slug, and some other settings for the module go here
  }

  function get_fields() {
    // This method returns an array of fields that the module will
    // display as the module settings
  }

  function shortcode_callback($atts, $content = null, $function_name) {
    // This method returns the content the module will display
  }
}
new YOUR_MODULE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 3):

The code above didn't work
The function needs to be called as well.

Here's an example with working code from https://divi.space/blog/adding-custom-modules-to-divi/

```
function DS_Custom_Modules(){
 if(class_exists("ET_Builder_Module")){
 include("ds-custom-modules.php");
 }
}

function Prep_DS_Custom_Modules(){
 global $pagenow;

$is_admin = is_admin();
 $action_hook = $is_admin ? 'wp_loaded' : 'wp';
 $required_admin_pages = array( 'edit.php', 'post.php', 'post-new.php', 'admin.php', 'customize.php', 'edit-tags.php', 'admin-ajax.php', 'export.php' ); // list of admin pages where we need to load builder files
 $specific_filter_pages = array( 'edit.php', 'admin.php', 'edit-tags.php' );
 $is_edit_library_page = 'edit.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && 'et_pb_layout' === $_GET['post_type'];
 $is_role_editor_page = 'admin.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['page'] ) && 'et_divi_role_editor' === $_GET['page'];
 $is_import_page = 'admin.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['import'] ) && 'wordpress' === $_GET['import']; 
 $is_edit_layout_category_page = 'edit-tags.php' === $pagenow && isset( $_GET['taxonomy'] ) && 'layout_category' === $_GET['taxonomy'];

if ( ! $is_admin || ( $is_admin && in_array( $pagenow, $required_admin_pages ) && ( ! in_array( $pagenow, $specific_filter_pages ) || $is_edit_library_page || $is_role_editor_page || $is_edit_layout_category_page || $is_import_page ) ) ) {
 add_action($action_hook, 'DS_Custom_Modules', 9789);
 }
}
Prep_DS_Custom_Modules();
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning ... your custom slug in the "ds-custom-modules.php" file MUST contain the string "et_pb_", or it will be filtered out by the function et_pb_allowed_modules_list(). This isn't mentioned in the example, and took me hours to figure out!!

Answer (score 2):

I want to try settling the little debate here.
class ET_Builder_Module_Custom_Module extends ET_Builder_Module {} actually works and main-modules.php can be modified freely **IF a Child Theme** is used. 
I recently ajaxified a Divi Theme and after update everything worked like a charm.

Note: It's always a good idea to check if there are  updates on the files you use inside the child theme because sometimes you may need to update the child files also.

I hope this helped all future readers of this post.

HFGL with the new modules you are about to create ;)

Comment: Do you happen to have sample code or a tutorial that you can share?

Comment: Hi I guess the answer is a bit late but you can actually use what Oterox have as code but inside a child themes main-modules.php

Answer (score 0):

For creating custom modules, I would use existing modules to create a design (layout), would save that design into Divi library and would use Text or Code modules and would write all HTML/jquery code there.

Like here, https://github.com/Skaidrius/Divi/tree/master/Layouts/Price-list

Answer (score -2):

You can do it modifying the Divi theme files (which is bad)

For example, you can modify main-modules.php to add a new module:

```
class ET_Builder_Module_Custom_Module extends ET_Builder_Module {
    function init() {
        $this->name = __( 'My Module', 'et_builder' );
        $this->slug = 'et_pb_custom_module';
```

After that you need to add the panel for the customizer in functions.php:

```
/* Section: Custom Module */
$wp_customize->add_section( 'et_pagebuilder_custom_module', array(
    'priority'       => 220,
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'title'          => __( 'My Module', 'Divi' ),
    // 'description'    => '',
) );
```

If you do a search in functions.php you'll find where to add it easily ;)

Comment: No one should touch those files which you have specified here. Hooks are there to do that.

Comment: You can do that (change PHP files of original theme) if you copied these files to your child theme only (to be correct, you can change this file in child theme directory). In another case, you will lose everything after theme update and also it could have a negative influence on theme functionality and vulnerability.